# Reparametrizing a Uniform Prior Distribution to Multivariate Standard Normal

Tags: bayesian, inference, likelihood, prior

## Problem Description

I have a posterior distribution
$$
p(\theta\mid y) \propto p(y \mid \theta) p(\theta)
$$
with a uniform prior $p(\theta)= \mathcal{U}([a, b]^n)$, which is **bounded**. However, for my particular application, it's easier to work with an **unbounded** prior so *I would like to reparametrize the problem to work with a multivariate standard normal distribution*
$$
z\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I_m).
$$
How does the posterior distribution become after the reparametrization? I would like to find an expression for
$$
p(z\mid y) \propto p(y\mid z) p(z)
$$
where prior and likelihood are in terms of the original ones and so that this posterior distribution is equivalent.

## Reparametrizing the Prior

Suppose I can find a diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $z = f(\theta)$. Then by the change of variables formula
$$
p_z(z) = p_\theta(f^{-1}(z)) |J_{f^{-1}}(z)|.
$$
Luckily, [it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) that
$$
\theta = a + (b - a) F_z(z).
$$

## Reparametrizing the Likelihood

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: that's the easy part friend, you just plug in the transformed value to the likelihood.

Comment: @JohnMadden So are you saying that the posterior is this?
$$
p(z\mid y) \propto p(y \mid f^{-1}(z)) p_\theta(f^{-1}(z)) |J_{f^{-1}}(z)|
$$
How come though?